# Twitch API, Stream URL

Tags: android, json, api, stream, twitch

I have started a small android project and its last feature is watching twitch streams but I have run into a setback. I have red the twitch [API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API) and later found [this post](http://www.johannesbader.ch/2014/01/find-video-url-of-twitch-tv-live-streams-or-past-broadcasts/) . My idea is the following:

-get the list of twitch streamers for a particular game.

-when an element of the list is clicked open the stream and play.

After reading those two sources I made a listfragment with arrayadapter and using volley I loaded the response from https ://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=(MyGame) .
ex:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=League%20of%20Legends
```

I get JSON reponse for the 25 top streamers and display them. Here is where I run in a problem. I don't know how to get the streams video URL.

According to my second link to get the different quiality stream videos I have to:

1) get token from http ://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/(CHANNELNAME)/access_token

The response recieved looks like this:

```
{ token: "{"user_id":null,"channel":"riotgames","expires":1408096127,"chansub":{"view_until":1924905600,"restricted_bitrates":[]},"private":{"allowed_to_view":true},"privileged":false}",
sig: "c81dfc25b90d44ea107cdeae5371df28185bd0dd",
mobile_restricted: false
}
```

this response has 3 values: token, sig and mobile_restricted.

2) using this http ://usher.twitch.tv/select/(CHANNELNAME).json?nauthsig=(SIG)&nauth=(TOKEN)&allow_source=true , I fill in the fields using the json token response

```
http://usher.twitch.tv/select/riotgames.json?nauthsig=c81dfc25b90d44ea107cdeae5371df28185bd0dd&nauth="{"user_id":null,"channel":"riotgames","expires":1408096127,"chansub":{"view_until":1924905600,"restricted_bitrates":[]},"private":{"allowed_to_view":true},"privileged":false}"&allow_source=true
```

, but the response I get back is always:

```
[]
```

Which to my understanding means that the stream is not live? But in the same time I can see the stream going.

My questions are: How do I get the live stream urls with the different qualities? What is wrong with the way I call them?

As a disclaimer: I'm extremely new to any sort of programming so I don't pretend to  understand everything. I might have overlooked something or clearly missed it. Also it seems I can't post more than 2 links so I have added an additional space after http.

Edit: With the help of @rcxrdx I got the response I was looking for. What he pointed out was that I have to encode the token correctly. Here is an example of encoded url for recieving the String response with all the video qualities:

```
http://usher.twitch.tv/select/reckful.json?segment_preference=2&player=twitchweb&nauth=%7B%22user_id%22%3Anull%2C%22channel%22%3A%22reckful%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1408897471%2C%22chansub%22%3A%7B%22view_until%22%3A1924905600%2C%22restricted_bitrates%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22private%22%3A%7B%22allowed_to_view%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22privileged%22%3Afalse%7D&allow_source=true&type=any&nauthsig=b0e19347528f3675612d4c5d1a030bfa8d9ffb13
```

Something I lost some time to is that when you recieve the access token if you are not logged in the user_id will return null. In most examples like the one from the blog post i have added up top, do not explicitly say that. So yeah, if someone wants to play a twitch video the hierarchy is as follows: get access_token, form the url following my example in the edit , recieve the STRING (it might say it's JSON but it isnt) response, get the video qualities from the response and use a VideoView to play them with the following lines:

```
String myStream=response;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(myStream);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, the only thing you are missing is that your token has to be URL-encoded, by the method of your choice.

If you want to make sure that you are doing the encoding step correctly, you can watch the request you send when connecting to a stream through your browser (with wireshark, or the Network tab on Chrome), and make sure you are sending the same token.

Comment: I hate to ask, but could you elaborate? If you have the time could you give me an example ?

Here is what I don't understand and can't find answer somewhere else:
-what does "URL encoded" mean ? What I fill in the missing pieces in the url example.

As to wireshark, I saw it mentioned somewhere and installed it but since i`m very inexperienced i have almost no idea what to look for. I used this filter: http.request.uri contains twitch . And i got some results but I'm not sure how to interpret them since they differ a lot from the examples above.

Comment: /select/trumpsc.json?type=any&p=1903171&private_code=&segment_preference=2&player=twitchweb&nauth=%7B%22user_id%22%3A47958526%2C%22channel%22%3A%22trumpsc%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1408400876%2C%22chansub%22%3A%7B%22view_until%22%3A1924905600%2C%22restricted_bitrates%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22private%22%3A%7B%22allowed_to_view%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22privileged%22%3Afalse%7D&allow_source=true&nauthsig=7d7bbf4ba062914488f15820f83bc0184be9f349 HTTP/1.1   

 This was the response I got from twitch when I used the above filter. Or at least this is what I think was essential out of the response ?

Comment: You got what was essential here, it is the select request sent when you were loading the stream, the same one that you are trying to replicate.

It is made of a few different elements, some of them are unnecessary, and as you had seen before, you need the "nauth", and "nauthsig" in order to have an answer with the stream URLs.

Comment: Here, in the request that you have captured :

nauth = %7B%22user_id%22%3A47958526%2C%22channel%22%3A%22trumpsc%22%2C%‌22expires%22%3A1408400876%2C%22chansub%22%3A%7B%22view_until%22%3A1924905600%2C%2‌2restricted_bitrates%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22private%22%3A%7B%22allowed_to_view%22%3A‌​true%7D%2C%22privileged%22%3Afalse%7D

nauthsig = 7d7bbf4ba0629144‌​88f15820f83bc0184be9f349

In the nauth field, you are supposed to enter the token you got earlier, but as you see it is different, the special characters have been replaced by "%X" with X being their hex encoding. This process is URL encoding.

Comment: If you do the same thing, and end up sending the same request, you will get the URLs, the same way your browser received them.

So you can check what you are sending, if it is correctly encoded, if you don't have escape characters appearing ("\") or any other reason why you are not sending the right token

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it in 1 hour max!

Comment: Thank you! I got the right response. When I get the stream working on android I will edit my main question with the response and will highlight what you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how much this will help you but i was doing work with the twitch API a few months ago I found it very hard but was able to get game searches working and to bring in streams

hope it helps here is the code that i used

//Twitch Streams
//Ref: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/embedding.md

```
function getTwitch(title){
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q="+title+"&limit=20&type=top&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams.slice(0,5), function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<a target='frame1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'><button>"+item.channel.display_name+"</button></a><br />";
    });
    $("#StreamList").html(temp);
});
}
```

Here is a sample jsfiddle i build using the original api code that u my use as a jumping of point aswell but the code above is the final code I used

http://jsfiddle.net/F4tsM/10/

Comment: Yes I found similar code examples too. But the response I get from using the search function isn't much help to me. It doesnt contain a tag for the actual stream link (or at least I can not see/understand it). It provides similar info as the list that I use(thumbnails,viewers count, channel link,streamer etc.). And the second link is just for embedding the stream. Still, thank you for taking the time.

Comment: well sry i cant be more help